# Is it okay to dispatch slice's action from another action in redux-toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux-toolkit and have 2 slices: "auth" and "profile"

auth => handle information about token
profile => handle information about user account

When user tries to login, I send request to api, that returns me the user token and account information. Then I need to save this information. I put token to corresponding field (in same slice). And I need to put my account information to "profile" slice (login processing takes place in the "auth" slice). Now i'm just dispatch setProfile action from 'auth' slice.

Is it anti-pattern to dispatch "profile" action from "auth" slice?
Or I have to move this logic from redux to component?
Or make "login" action outside of slice?
Or do I need to keep it all in one slice?

```js
// PROFILE SLICE | profile.js 

const initialState = {
  data: {},
  status: 'idle'
}

export const profileSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'profile',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setProfile(s, {payload: profile}) {
      s.profile = profile
    }
  }
})

export const {setProfile} = userSlice.actions;
export default profileSlice.reducer


// AUTH SLICE | auth.js

import {setProfile} from './profile' // import action creator from profile slice

const initialState = {
  token: null,
  status: 'idle'
}

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setToken(s, {payload: token}) {
      s.token = token
    }
  }
})

export const login = ({email, password}) => dispatch => {
  return api.auth.login({
    email,
    password
  })
    .then(res => {
      const {token, ...profile} = res.data
      dispatch(setToken(token))
      dispatch(setProfile(profile)
    })
}

export const {setToken} = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer
```

Comment: you have few options. - dispatch another action from your success handler. or you can write middleware (or use some) to observe the actions and dispatch another if there is your success auth action being processed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't dispatch actions inside of a slice / reducer, although you can certainly dispatch actions from within a thunk wherever it's written.

However, you can *listen* for another slice's actions in any other reducer, and in fact this is a pattern we encourage:

- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#model-actions-as-events-not-setters
- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action

The one thing to be aware of when doing that is that if two different slices depend on each other, you can end up with a "circular import dependency" issue, in which case you need to extract some common functionality in order to break the import cycle:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#exporting-and-using-slices

In this specific case, I see that you're actually separating out the `token` value from the rest of the data. I would suggest dispatching a *single* action that has all the received login data, and let both slice reducers pick out the pieces that they care about.

Comment: But where I have to place this action? Create some slice for "common" actions?

Comment: Or do I need to put some thunk in root reducer, name it like "login" and from it dispatch actions from "auth" and "profile" reducers?

Comment: Sorry again, I just have a bit of experience with redux, I have one more variant. 
Maybe I can dispatch thunk in root reducer (dispatch(initUser)).  And then, in this thunk, dispatch action (dispatch("userInited")) with all needed information. And from 'auth' and 'profile' reducers I have to listen this action? Is it right? for me, it seems like this option looks the most convenient

Comment: @eugenedrvnk To me a thunk dispatching an action doesn't make a lot of sense. You could just react to the thunk actions from within whichever slice, using `extraReducers`. 
Take a look at: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk